# No setter/field for postImage found on class

Tags: java, android

```html
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for postImage found on class com.example.newjunk.Model.Post (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
    No setter/field for postImage found on class com.example.newjunk.Model.Post (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
```

I am new to Android development and I am getting the following error:-

W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for postImage found on class com.example.newjunk.Model.Post (fields/setters are case sensitive!)

package com.example.newjunk.Model;

public class Post {

```
private String postid;
private String postimage;
private String description;
private String publisher;

public Post(String postid, String postimage, String description, String publisher) {
    this.postid = postid;
    this.postimage = postimage;
    this.description = description;
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public Post() {
}

public String getPostid() {
    return postid;
}

public void setPostid(String postid) {
    this.postid = postid;
}

public String getPostimage() {
    return postimage;
}

public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
    this.postimage = postimage;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}
```

}

and the

PostAdapter.java

public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
public Context mContext;
public List<Post> mPost;

private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPost = mPost;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item,viewGroup,false);

    return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    Post post = mPost.get(i);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage()).into(viewHolder.post_image);

    if(post.getDescription().equals("")){
        viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
    }

    publisherInfo(viewHolder.image_profile,viewHolder.username,viewHolder.publisher,post.getPublisher());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPost.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView image_profile, post_image, like, comment, save;

    public TextView username, likes, publisher, description, comments;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        publisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);




    }
}

private void publisherInfo(final ImageView image_profile, final TextView username, final TextView publisher, final String userid){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            publisher.setText(user.getUsername());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace

Comment: I'm guessing you used `setPostImage()` instead of `setPostimage()` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @ElliotM full stack trace?